# TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x00000000

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I got error while learning the Machine Learning and i am not finding help on internet can someone help me correct it:

```
model= Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3),input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size(2,2)))
```

The error i'm getting is:

```
<ipython-input-33-e2cf34866813> in <module>
      1 model= Sequential()
      2 
----> 3 model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3),input_shape=input_shape))
      4 model.add(Activation('relu'))
      5 model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size(2,2)))
```

TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x000000000504F860>

Comment: This sounds like you are mixing keras and tf.keras

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Sir i import it like this: from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D

Comment: Please include all imports, a single import does not say anything

Comment: from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

from keras.models import Sequential

from keras.layers import Activation,Dropout,Flatten,Dense

from keras import backend as K

from keras.preprocessing import image

from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D

from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD

Comment: See? You are importing both from keras and tf.keras, that will not work, you have to make all imports from one of the libraries